# Python signal between functions to remove busy waiting

Tags: python, observer-pattern, busy-waiting

I'm just trying to implement a simple Observer pattern in Python and am running into an issue. This is my code:

```
class Observable:
    def __init__(self):
    self.__observers = []

    def register_observer(self, observer):
        self.__observers.append(observer)

    def notify_observers(self, data):
        for observer in self.__observers:
            observer.notify(self, data)

class Observer:

    def __init__(self, observable):
        observable.register_observer(self)
        self.data_present = False
        self.data = ''

    def notify(self, observable, data):
        self.data_present = True
        self.data = data

    def wait(self):
        while True:
            if not self.data_present:
                time.sleep(5)

            else:
                break

        return self.data
```

In here, I would like to eliminate the busy waiting in Observer.wait() (the line time.sleep(5). How can I perhaps signal to this function?

Comment: Is this not something where you can use asyncio?

Comment: Have a look at the examples for the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) module.

In particular, you may want to use [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine).

Comment: @Evert, I want my observers to be synchronous, and wait for a message to be published before they go ahead with execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the `wait` function at all -- just do what you need to in `notify` (process the data, log the data, mutilate/spindle/fold the data, whatever).

If you are using threading, check out the [Queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class:  it allows for multiple threads to synchronize on data availability without busy-waiting -- just have the `notify` method push data into a `Queue`, and `wait` can wait on it.  Note that there is probably a more elegant solution using some of the other features found in the [Threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module.

As a side note, you also don't need the double-underscore in `self.__observers` -- just `self.observers` is fine.

Comment: I want my observers to be synchronous. I want them to wait until there is data that has been published before going forward with the execution. I think that if I do everything in notify, wouldn't my observers be asynchronous?

Comment: Are you using threading?  If not, everything is synchronous already.  If you are using threading then check out the `Queue` -- your `notify` can submit the data to it, and your `wait` (or whatever you actually call it) can simply try to `get` from the `Queue` which will block until data shows up (without busy-waiting).  As for `notify`, only the `Observable` calls it, so nothing in there runs until there is data available.

Comment: Yep, I was using threading. This solution works fine enough. Is there a problem if there are many instances of Queue.Queue() created when I have more than a few threads running?                                                                                            PS: Can you edit your answer with this information so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yield` to suspend a function at one point, waiting for some value (blocked, **without doing busy waiting**).

```
def f():
    print('f: i am waiting for something...')
    c = yield
    print('f: i got %s' % c)
    yield None
```

On the other side you call `.send(val)` to resume its execution:

```
>>> g=f()
>>> next(g)
f: i am waiting for something...
>>> g.send(123)
f: i got 123
>>>
```

Note the additional `yield None` at the end of `f()` which prevents a `StopIteration` exception from being `raise`d when you call `.send()`.